# Generic.List: How to set/get position/currentitem for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, bindingsource

I'm currenty working on a DataGridView-extentsion with custom DataSource handling. If I bind a list to two normal System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView and select an item in dataGridView1, dataGridView2 automatically also sets the position to the item.

If I assign a BindingSource I can handle the PositionChanged event, but a Generic.List doesn't have a CurrencyManager, so how does the dataGridView2 know the new position?

Comment: what is a role of CurrencyManager in all this ?

Comment: @Tigran, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx). It's not related to money currencies ;)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer: BindingContext!

A simple example:

```
public class ModifiedCollection : BindingSource {
    BindingSource Source {get;set;}
    BindingManagerBase bmb;
    Control Parent;

    public ModifiedCollection(object Source, Control Parent) {
        if ((this.Source = Source as BindingSource) == null) {
            this.Source = new BindingSource();
            this.Source.DataSource = Source;
        }

        this.Source.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(Source_ListChanged);


        this.Parent = Parent;
        this.Parent.BindingContextChanged += new EventHandler(Parent_BindingContextChanged);
    }

    void Parent_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (bmb != null) {
            bmb.PositionChanged -= bmb_PositionChanged;
        }
        if (Parent.FindForm().BindingContext.Contains(this.Source.DataSource)) {
            bmb = Parent.BindingContext[this.Source.DataSource];
            if (bmb != null) {
                bmb.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(bmb_PositionChanged);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but now you bind to this source and not to the List do you? - but I tell you what: glad you found it - give you an upvote and you can close this ;)

Comment: no, i'm still binding the list. the upper part is only to know if it already is a bindingsource. example: var m = new ModifiedCollection(list1 /*Generic List*/, this /*Datagridview or Form or any other component*/);

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the current position of some DataGridView (having the as list as DataSource) from the List?
Then the answer is: you cannot. The list knows nothing of the connected view - shown element included (of course)

Alternative to get the info from the DataGridView:
subscribe to the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event of the DataGridView and set the index of the second accordingly - for both you should be able to use the [CurrentCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell%28VS.80%29.aspx)-property

You cannot do such things as you described in your comments below without knowing something of the DataGridView.
It's a different design - you could implement your own "ShowableList" or something and try creating your own DataGridView that shows the indicated item from your ShowableList and sets the ShownIndex in there too - but you have to do this yourself.

Comment: i don't believe the standard datagridview does it this way. there must be some kind of trick behind this. with your solution i must listen to all container controls Control.Added event and listen to all datagridviews SelectionChanged and DataSourceChanged event. there must be another way.

Comment: you want to bind two datagridviews together if I get your question - the standard-view won't this at all. And you List will certainly not know what element is shown so you have to use the datagridviews-abilities if you want to use it with a general List (or collection). Maybe I'm wrong or I didn't get you question right, so please explain.

Comment: i only made an example with datagridview. another exaple would be: Assign listX to dataGridView1 and to a textbox1. if i select another item in the dataGridView1 the textbox also jumps to the selected item. it's not only between datagridview, but between all components which has a the list as datasource. there must be any way to get the current item for a genery list.